# If Function between 2 values is there a smarter way VBA Excel Macro?

Tags: excel, vba

Hey guys I apologize if this is vague: I'm wondering if there is a smarter way to write this code:

```
If i < 6 Then
j = 1
ElseIf i > 6 And i <= 9 Then
j = 2
ElseIf i > 9 And i <= 12 Then
j = 3
ElseIf i > 12 And i < 15 Then
j = 4
Else
End If
```

The issue is that the value 'i' is dependent on a user input. The max limit for i is 3*N where N is a user input. E.g. In this case the program works where n=5 as you can see it goes up to 15.

But what if I wanted an input of n=10? Sure I could repeat this code but it doesn't seem 'smart' or intuitive. There must be a smarter way to do this. Can anyone help? Thanks. Newb programmer btw.

Comment: Your ranges are not consistent (included / excluded). If you had `i <= 6` and `i <= 15`, it would be `if i <= 6 then j = 1 else j = (i - 7) \ 3 + 2`.

Comment: Damn, that worked. Thank you very much. Was there a method how you came up with that formula or was it just algebra which you used? Curious to know.

Comment: Algebra? No, basic math.

Comment: `select case` is the right structure for this I think

Comment: I think select case is good however it really depends on whats inputted. I'd like to approve your answer @GSerg, is there an option for this ..?

Comment: @apang [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66027032/11683) is better, accept that instead. Maybe replace the `Int((i - 1) / 3)` with `(i - 1) \ 3)` because it's cleaner.

Comment: I just tested it, looks like it needs the Int for it to work.

Comment: @apang You probably confused ``\`` and `/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If i <= 6 Then
    j = 1
Else
    j = Int((i - 1) / 3)
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Select Case is for such selections:

```vb
Select Case i
    Case <= 6 
        j = 1
    Case <= 9
        j = 2
    Case <= 12
        j = 3
    case <= 15 
        j = 4
    Case Else
        j = 5
End Select
```

Or perhaps simply:

```
j = i \ 3 - 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the input dude, that wasn't me for the record.

Comment: @apang You are harming this website by upvoting wrong answers. We value correctness of content here, not the effort of answering. Neither this `select case` nor the formula give you the correct answer. E.g. for i = 8 you want j = 2, this will give you 1.

Comment: My bad. Understood for future postings.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do it as a simple calculation, which will catch all values of N, assuming that the gap between values of j (blocks of 3) isn't affected by N. You just have to deal with the initial block of 6 that converts to 1 (I'm assuming your first line should say <= 6, rather than <6, otherwise your code will ignore a value of i=6:

```
j = Int(WorksheetFunction.Max(3, i-1) / 3)
```

If you do really want to do nothing if your value is outside (greater than) the range, you could then test the value of j afterwards

```
If j <= 3*N Then
    'Your processing goes here, otherwise nothing happens
End If
```

Comment: At i = 8 this gives 1, should give 2.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, subtracted 3 instead of 1, incomplete testing :-/.  I've changed my answer.

Answer (score -1):

If the number is integer then `select case` with `To` keyword

```
Select case i
  Case Is < 6
    j = 1
  Case 6 To 9
    j = 2
  Case 10 To 12
    j = 3
  Case 13, 14
    j = 4
  Case Else
End Select
```

Comment: Because the question is "How to write this `select case` for unbounded number of cases" (you have written only up to 14). The answer is "you can't, use [a formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66027032/11683) instead".

Comment: The question doesnt say unbounded - thats only your vocabulary not the original question, it just says a smarter way to write, so I your downvote is not appropriate because you are downvoting based on your own subjective interpretation of the question, not the question that was originally written @GSerg

Comment: Please read the question. *"But what if I wanted an input of n=10? Sure I could repeat this code but it doesn't seem 'smart' or intuitive"*. At n = 10, the `select case` would need to be extended to `Case 30`, because *"The max limit for i is 3*N where N is a user input"*.